# Limit of a non-summable sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Suppose we have a sequence $\{b_k\}$ whose sum is unbounded, $$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}  b_k = + \infty, $$
with $$\lim_k b_k = 0. $$
(e.g $\sum_k\frac{1}{k}$ will satisfy the above). Can we say anything about the following sum :
$$\lim_n \sum_{i=n}^{n+m(n)} b_i , \,\,\text{where }\,\, m(n) \to \infty. $$
Specifically, will the above limit tend to infinity or will it stay bounded/ go to zero (because $\lim_nb_n\to0$)?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You may test your limit in the case of the harmonic series with $m(n) =\lfloor an\rfloor$ for $a>0$.

Comment: It's quite possible your sum will be $0$ for infinitely many $n.$

Comment: thanks for the comment, but i think the answer by Robert Z. is enough to get the result i want

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you can not say much about that limit. Take the [harmonic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)#Rate_of_divergence) then as $n$ goes to infinity,
$$\sum_{k=n}^{n+m(n)} \frac{1}{k}\sim\ln(n+m(n))-\ln(n-1)=\ln\left(1+\frac{m(n)}{n}\right)$$
and the above limit is $+\infty$ for $m(n)=n^2$ and it is $\ln(1+k)$ for $m(n)=kn$ with $k\in\mathbb{N}^+$.

P.S. Actually, by choosing properly a sequence of signs $a_k\in\{-1,1\}$
and the function $m(n)$ then the limit of $\sum_{k=n}^{n+m(n)} \frac{a_k}{k}$ could be negative or it could even not exist.